# eval() works in MacOS but not Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev, eclipse-juno

I'm working through Python Programming (For Python 3) by John Zelle and up until recently had been doing all my work on a MacBook Pro running 10.7. I'm working in Eclipse Juno on both platforms. I decided to move all my projects to my PC with Windows 7 and imported them into Eclipse Juno. I noticed that every app with an `eval(input())` was broken, yet they had all worked on the Macbook. The same is new for any code I enter from the book. Why does this work on one platform but not the other? Here's an example of code that works in MacOS but not Windows:

```
def main():
    sum = 0.0
    count = 0
    xStr = input("Enter a number (<Enter> to quit) >> ")
    while xStr != "":
        x = eval(xStr)
        sum = sum + x
        count = count + 1
        xStr = input("Enter a number (<Enter> to quit) >> ")
    print("\nThe average of the numbers is", sum / count)

main()
```

This works fine on the Mac but spits out this error in Windows:

```
Enter a number (<Enter> to quit) >> 5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nostromo\workspace\Chapter 11\average4.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Nostromo\workspace\Chapter 11\average4.py", line 12, in main
    x = eval(xStr)
  File "<string>", line 1
    5    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Could it be that your Windows system defaults to Python 2 instead of 3?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I don't think so. If it were, it would have given a `eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object`. `xStr` does appear to be a string.

Comment: @David, you're right, Python's `eval()` only takes strings. Looks like the interpreter is parsing `5` as a prefix of some kind. That's strange.

Comment: It's 3 for certain. `sys.version` reports `3.0 (r30:67507, Dec  3 2008, 19:44:23) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]` when tested from Eclipse.

Comment: My guess is a newline related issue. (Aside: don't use 3.0 when 3.3 is already out)

Comment: That was the problem. I was certain I had installed 3.3.0 but I guess that was on another PC. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change input() to raw_input()?

Comment: I know that would work as I have several older projects that use that instead.

Comment: So, can you confirm Python versions on both machines by running `python --version`?

Comment: You may be onto the reason dusty. Mac is 3.3.0 and Windows is just 3.0. Installing 3.3.0 to see if that resolves this.

Comment: After updating to 3.3.0, the errors went away. That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`eval(input())` is a silly way to get what you want anyway, and the author of the book shouldn't have suggested you use it.  Change it to `int(input())`, and you'll be much happier.

Comment: Sure. I know that, but would still be left with doubts without resolving the why of this.